# "Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]" error

Tags: sql, hibernate

When I run my `createStudentDemo` class I get the following error:

```
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.11.Final}

Exception in thread "main"
org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not
locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] at
org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:53) at
org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:215) at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:244)
at
com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.CreateStudentDemo.main(CreateStudentDemo.java:15)
```

I don't understand why I have this error.

Here is the code of my `createStudentDemo` class:

```java
package com.luv2code.hibernate.demo;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity.Student;

public class CreateStudentDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create session factory

        SessionFactory factory= new Configuration()
                                    .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                                    .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                                    .buildSessionFactory();

        // create session
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try {
            //create a student object
            System.out.println("creating new student object");
            Student tempStudent = new Student("Paul", "Wall", "paul@luv2code.com");

            //start a transaction
            session.beginTransaction();

            // save the student object
            System.out.println("Saving the student...");
            session.save(tempStudent);

            //commit transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();
                System.out.println("Done !");
        }
        finally {
            factory.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the code for my class student:

```java
package com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {

    public Student() {
    }
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {

        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }
}
```

and here is the code of my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file:

```xml
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
            "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
            "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-configuration>

        <session-factory>

            <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
            <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
            <property name="connection.username">hbstudent</property>
            <property name="connection.password">hbstudent</property>

            <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
            <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

            <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

            <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>

            <!-- Set the current session context -->
            <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        </session-factory>

    </hibernate-configuration>
```

and here is the location of my files:

[image: location files]

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `hibernate.cfg.xml` should be in classpath. Put it in `src` folder.